# how to color chaged image last point and first point in google-map

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-polyline

We get 4 latitude and 4 longitude.We drag line between points using `Polyline`

```
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: flightPlanCoordinates2,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
  });  
  flightPath.setMap(map);
```

We Add Image on points like this

```
var image ='../images/shopimageformapsyellow.png';
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:mapCenter,
    map: map,
    icon: image
 });
```

Working fine But 4 points have one image like yellow color image.We need `Start and Ended point redcolor image` and remaining Yellow color image.Please guide me any one how to place first point and last point have different image

We tried like this

```
var icons1 = {
          start: new google.maps.MarkerImage('../images/startRed.png'),
          end: new google.maps.MarkerImage('../images/startGreen.png')
         };



flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                  icons: [{
                        icon: icons1,
                    }],
                path: flightPlanCoordinates2,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.35
              });  
            flightPath.setMap(map);
```

But we don't have luck Please any one guide me

Comment: See this [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-custom) and the corresponding [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#IconSequence). For polylines, icons are symbols. Not images. If you need an image at start and end locations, place a [marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) at each end with a custom icon.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Leaflet which is a open source Javascript library for Mobile Friendly interactive maps.

With that you can have custom image for markers and also alternative colors for marker images.

Please refer to the following [link](http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons.html) for more details.

Hope that Helps!!